# Calling javascript function with an objectstring in dot notation

Tags: javascript, string, function, object

Suppose I have the string:

```
var string = "function";
```

With

```
window[string];
```

I can call a function with the name of "function".

But, when I have:

```
var string2 = "function.method.weHaveTogoDeeper";
```

it should call

```
window["function"]["method"]["weHaveTogoDeeper"]
```

I can't do:

```
window[string2]
```

in this case. I dont know the number of "." in the string, so I need some kind of routine.

Comment: I was almost asking same question, would upvote 10 times :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can split the string across `.` by using the `String.split` method:

```
var string2 = "function.method.weHaveTogoDeeper";
var methods = string2.split(".");
```

In this examples, `methods` will be the array `["function","method","weHaveTogoDeeper"]`. You should now be able to do a simple iteration over this array, calling each function on the result of the previous one.

#### Edit

The iteration I had in mind was something like this:

```
var result = window;
for(var i in methods) {
    result = result[methods[i]];
}
```

In your example, `result` should now hold the same output as

```
window["function"]["method"]["weHaveTogoDeeper"]
```

Comment: foo.bar is not a property of window, even though foo might be. You have to dereference foo before you can access it's property bar.

Answer (score 6):

```
function index(x,i) {return x[i]}
string2.split('.').reduce(index, window);
```

> **edit:** Of course if you are calling functions from strings of their names, you are likely doing something inelegant which would be frowned upon, especially in a collaborative coding settings. The only use case I can think of that is sane is writing a testing framework, though there are probably a few more cases. So please use caution when following this answer; one should instead use arrays, or ideally direct references.

Comment: hooray for functional programming.

Comment: `reduce` is not supported widely by every browser (except for most modern browsers)

Comment: @Mrchief: I disagree, though thanks for not saying "it's not standard", and for correctly saying most modern browsers support it.  =) I get some variant of this comment every time I use `.map` or `.foreach` (they are in the JavaScript/ECMAscript specification!), and are supported by all browsers. http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/ If supporting ancient versions of Internet Explorer (8 and lower) is an issue, include https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce#Compatibility if you detect IE8.

Comment: I believe you can use underscore.js to provide the reduce function when the executing browser doesn't have it natively

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one a while back:

```
function RecursiveMapper(handlerName, stack) {
    // check if empty string
    if(!handlerName || handlerName === '' || (handlerName.replace(/\s/g,'') === '')) return null;

    var buf = handlerName.split('.');
    stack = stack || window;
    return (buf.length === 1) ? stack[buf[0]] : this.RecursiveMapper(buf.slice(1).join('.'), stack[buf[0]]);
}
```

Call it like this: `RecursiveMapper(window[string2]);`

This one also checks if the function is defined in `window` scope first and returns the global one fi found.