# How would i go about getting a specific object based on the value of a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have separate javascript files to load custom objects; these objects are designed to extend some default parameters when the main function is read

they each look like

```
 var str1= { path:'url1:, var1:5};
 var str2= { path:'url2:, var1:3};
 etc...
```

I have an array of strings(that is generated from loading an rss page) and i want to return the object based on if its name matches the object name. hardcoding it would kind of defeat the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645585/calling-javascript-function-with-an-objectstring-in-dot-notation/6645620#6645620). It shows how to reference objects by using strings. The only difference I can see is that rather than starting with the `window` object, you would start at whatever object defines your current scope (e.g. `this`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the square bracket notation to refer to object properties whose key name is held in a variable:

```
var key = 'path';
var str1 = { path: 'url', var1: 1};
var value = str1[key]; // value == 'url';
```

You can also do:

```
var str1 = 'a';
var str2 = 'b';

var key = 'str1';
var value = window[key]; // value == 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = {  "string1": { path: "url1", var1:5},
             "string2": { path: "url2", var1:3} };
...
var url = map[yourstring].path;
```

Comment: Nice take on the question, though it deserves mention that this won't work if you've already written the code using actual variables as in the OP's example.